# Persistence of sorting answers per question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, sorting

Hello I usually browse with sorting by votes. Sometimes though I want to view certain questions(favorites that get a lot of answers even when they are old) sorting by newest answers.

As it is right now whenever I change to sorting by newest, then it changes globally and when I go to browse another question I have to change back to sorting by votes.

Therefore I propose a feature where sorting is persistent for a question. So if you sort by votes usually and go to question A and sort by newest and then go to question B. question B will be sorted by votes.

I'm not completely sure how this could work though because there would have to be defaults and such but what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would implement this without storing an obscene amount of data, either on the server or in cookies.  This would be per user/per question amounts of data.

Comment: Well you may not need to store anything except for the exceptions. For instance maybe a way to select "sort this question always by this way"

Comment: Okay, that might not be too bad.  Store each user's global default for all questions once, then store their preference for any question that they change from the default?  That would probably work out okay in most cases.

Comment: yea and you could even possibly have an expiration, like if they don't visit a question for a month then the sorting reverts to default